# How to use the sparse vector class in JScience?

Tags: java, jscience

I am trying to use the [sparse vector](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/vector/SparseVector.html) class in the JScience package but I am confused as to how. I want to make several sparse vectors of dimension, say, 1000. But, I see that there is no constructor and also suppose that I want to put certain values in a sparse vector at certain indexes, how is this supposed to be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Sparse vectors can be created using an index-to-element mapping or by adding single elements sparse vectors together.

This corresponds to the first two static `valueOf` methods.

---

#### [Single Element](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/vector/SparseVector.html#valueOf(int,%20F,%20int,%20F))

```
valueOf(int dimension, F zero, int i, F element)
```

> Returns a sparse vector having a single element at the specified index.

---

#### [Using a Mapping](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/vector/SparseVector.html#valueOf(int,%20F,%20java.util.Map))

```
valueOf(int dimension, F zero, java.util.Map<javolution.util.Index,F> elements)
```

> Returns a sparse vector from the specified index to element mapping.

Comment: So I could use a HashMap for example to make a sparse vector? And should I set `zero` to 0 if I want a sparse vector with zeros being the most abundant value?

Comment: @LucasAlanis Yes, you could use a HashMap. For the `zero` argument, you would provide the element of the particular field that represents zero. For example, if you were using a [Real](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/number/Real.html) field, you would pass `Real.ZERO`.